# How do I cancel a download in iTunes on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, itunes

I have selected to download a few podcasts in iTunes on my iPad but have decided that I don't want them anymore (they're audio only and I would prefer to listen to them on my laptop instead). Is there any way of terminating/cancelling the download?

I have tried tapping, holding, and various other things in iTunes on the iPad but no luck.

Am I doomed to have to download the files and then delete them?

I ask because I'm in a country that does **not** have unmetered download internet plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to swipe from left to right along the item to get a delete button. The same way you used to have to delete on the iPhone before they added in multi-item delete.

[image]

Comment: Great, that's just what I needed. Is there anywhere which documents these extra features?